# Rolling z-score or z-score?

Tags: standard-deviation, z-score, moving-window

Suppose that we have some time series data, in what context we use rolling z-score and when do we use z-score?

Comment: The question might well as include when we should use neither.  I think we need a more specific explanation of your context.